как войти в аккаунт твича с помощью логина и пароля Python?
Нужен способ войти в твич аккаунт без использования Twich api и client id OAUTH и т.д
Пытался войти через selenium, но пишет что браузер недоступен
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/')

a = input()  
time.sleep(5)  
driver.find_element (By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/nav/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button').click()  
time.sleep(6)  
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-username"]').send_keys("0xbym619vhss")  
time.sleep(3)  
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password-input"]').send_keys("********")  
time.sleep(3)  
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/div/button/div/div').click()


пытался и таким способом:
def get_random_chrome_user_agent():
    user_agent = UserAgent(browsers='chrome', os='windows', platforms='pc')
    return user_agent.random

def create_driver(user_id=1):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    base_directory = os.path.join(script_dir, 'users')
    user_directory = os.path.join(base_directory, f'user_{user_id}')

    options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={user_directory}')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    # options.add_argument('--headless')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    ua = get_random_chrome_user_agent()
    stealth(driver=driver,
            user_agent=ua,
            languages=["ru-RU", "ru"],
            vendor="Google Inc.",
            platform="Win32",
            webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
            renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
            fix_hairline=True,
            run_on_insecure_origins=True
            )

    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
        'source': '''
            delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array;
            delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise;
            delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol;
      '''
    })

    driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/')

    a = input()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element (By.XPATH,'//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/nav/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/button').click()
    time.sleep(6)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-username"]').send_keys("0xbym619vhss")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password-input"]').send_keys("********")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/div/button/div/div').click()
    time.sleep(100)
    a = input()
    return driver

get_random_chrome_user_agent()
create_driver()

желателен способ без использования мышки либо же что бы можно было заниматься своими делами во время выполнения нужной задачи
нашел решение, но не смог реализовать.
если запустить браузер Selenium типо как на андроиде, то твич не будет выдавать ошибку при входе.
